# Import fonts in Sage 9.0.10 - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, fonts, roots-sage

Since upgrading to **Sage 9.0.10**, I can't import my fonts. All my fonts (`.woff` & `woff2`) are in `assets>fonts`, in `main.scss @import "base/fonts"` and in `fonts.scss` I have this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Font";
  src: url("/../fonts/Font-name.woff2") format ("woff2"), url("/../fonts/Font-name.woff") 
  format("woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

With this, I have no error when I compile. I don't have this problem on my other projects.
I tested lots of things, modified the path or changed folder etc.

Maybe I have forgotten a little thing, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether that matters but how about removing the extra newline in the `src` part:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Font";
  src: url("/../fonts/Font-name.woff2") format ("woff2"), url("/../fonts/Font-name.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
```